# sd card mount fails with tryng to mount

Tags: linux-kernel, sd-card, buildroot, sdmmc

The SD Card over SPI driver and the board specific SPI Driver has been included in linux while the SD Card is being detected but the mounting is not successful. Please view the below log for reference.

```
# cd /
# ls
bin      init     linuxrc  opt      run      tmp
dev      lib      media    proc     sbin     usr
etc      lib64    mnt      root     sys      var

-----SD Card inserted-----

[ 1368.820495] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[ 1369.106903] mmc0: new SDHC card on SPI
[ 1369.811157] mmcblk0: mmc0:0000 SS08G 7.40 GiB 
[ 1371.203216]  mmcblk0: p1

# mount -t auto /dev/mmcblk0p1 /root/
mount: mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 on /root/ failed: No such file or directory
```

I have added the devtmpfs entry in the buildroot fstab file. I have checked the /dev and found that there is an entry for mmcblk0p1 and there is a directory called /root also at the root mountpoint. I am not able to find which is causing this issue.

Any help/guidence appreciated.

Comment: You are in the wrong site. This site is about programming. Unix and Linux site (check links on top right icons for all our sites) may be more appropriate. OTOH you should read the error messages: do you have /root/ directory? (and it is a bad choice to mount a card: /root/ was selected as special path in root (and not in home) in order to keep it into root filesystem.

Comment: the /root is the home directory in the build and I have also tried to create another directory test and mount to it. It failed still and I have found out that the issue was with the menuconfig when upgrading the linux kernel

Answer (score 1):

The linux while upgrading to newer kernel version the Filesystem support for ext3/4 was somehow resetted automatically. Upon enabling through menuconfig, compilation and test it was found to work as expected.